# Mapping objects to get inner object values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my objects

```
const objs = {
     "1":{
          "name":"Candice",
          "Classes": [00029,00023,00032,000222],
          "id":0002918
     },
     "2":{
           "name":"Clark",
           "classes":[000219,00029,00219],
           "id":00032
         }
}
```

I'm trying to get the id and name values inside to return the options for select.

```
const objKeys = Object.keys(objs); 
//const valueIds = objKeys.map(objs[value] => value.id);

objKeys.map((value, id) => (
    <option value={objs[value.id]}>{objs[value.name]}</option>
 ))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to add `return`?
`return <option value={objs[value.id]}>{objs[value.name]}</option>`

Comment: No. I dont believe so

Comment: @DanielKrom No, his lambda is a single expression. Implicit return should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `value` argument is actually a key

```
objKeys.map(key => (
    <option value={objs[key].id}>{objs[key].name}</option>
 ))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you dude! :)